# Response not received from ajax request in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page where there is table and each row has a icon for detailed information. When the icon is clicked, I get the unique identifier for that row into datastring and send a AJAX request. I get a response but cannot catch the correct response. Why is that I am doing wrong? I need to access the $desc in home.php , how to catch that in response ?

home.php

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actionone.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: true,  
        success:function() {
        alert("success"); 
    }
});
```

actionone.php

```
if(isset($_POST['content']))
{
$content=(int)$_POST['content'];
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT ISSUEDESCRIPTION FROM issues WHERE KBID =$content");
while($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))    
{   
    $desc = $rowe['ISSUEDESCRIPTION'];
}
```

Comment: You are only setting the value of `$dec` -> `$desc = $rowe['ISSUEDESCRIPTION'];`. You need to echo it in `actionone.php` -> `echo $desc;`. Then in `home.php` you need to access it in your success -> `success : function(data) { alert(data); }`

Comment: `while($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))    
{   
    $desc = $rowe['ISSUEDESCRIPTION'];
} echo json_encode($desc);`

Comment: You were not passing that `$data` from your php file you need to use `echo json_encode($data);` and within your `success: function(data){ console.log(data)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ajax success work you output some from php code
ie Change php code to

```
if(isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $content=(int)$_POST['content'];
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT ISSUEDESCRIPTION FROM issues WHERE KBID =$content");
    while($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($fetch))    
    {   
         $desc = $rowe['ISSUEDESCRIPTION'];
    }
    echo $desc;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actionone.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: true,  
        success:function(data) {
        alert(data.trim()); 
    }
});
```

Comment: OP wants to `access the $desc`. So instead of `echo "success";` it should be `echo $desc;`. Also, OP is not doing anything with the returned value in the `$.ajax()` success function.

Comment: I added echo line in actionone.php, then if I do alert in home.php , I am getting a javascript lines inside the alert. I am not receiving the $desc value. What to do now ?